# Iteration Of JSON Array Of Objects Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an array of objects that should be looking like this...

```
[{"Name":"blah","Description":"blah"},{"Name":"blah2","Description":"blah2"}]
```

Using Javascript/jQuery, how can I get the key/value pairs? I've tried many different ways but to no avail. When I try to get the length, it always returns the character count and iterates through each character and not the actual count of objects? When I run this, it returns an alert for [object Object], [object Object] spelled out by each character....

```
function DisplayItems(data) {
        $.each(data, function () {
            $.each(this, function (key, value) {
                alert(value);
            });
        });
}
```

Now that I look at this, is it not the array of objects I'm expecting? How can I actually return the string so I can actually see what's really in it and maybe go from there?

**EDIT:

This is my function to get the orders (cut out the crap and showing you an alert)... I call jQuery.Ajax and pass the returned data to displayOrders(data). The orders have a composite property of Items containing a list of Item.

```
function displayOrders(data) {
        $('#gdvOrders tbody').empty();
        for (var key in data.d) {
            alert(data.d[key].Items);
}
```

This is what I passed to displayItems, what you see in the alert function. I display the Orders in one table (hiding some columns including the Items), and want to display the Items for each order in another table when they select a row in the orders table. In the function shown above I can write...

```
data.d[key].OrderId
```

and it will display as normal. How do I display the properties for each item?

The jQuery.Ajax function is set to content-type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' and this is where I get the orders from...

```
[WebMethod]
    public static List<Order> GetOrdersByDept(Department department, Filter filter, DateTime? dateFrom = null, DateTime? dateTo = null)
    {
        return OrderLists.GetOrdersByDepartment((Department)department, (Filter)filter, dateFrom, dateTo);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

See this is working:

```
data=[{"Name":"blah","Description":"blah"},{"Name":"blah2","Description":"blah2"}]
data.forEach(function(i,j){

console.log("Name :"+i.Name+" Description :"+i.Description);


})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, simply use the `for .. in` loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            alert(key + " = " + obj[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/XWsvz/

Comment: Hi, your solution works perfectly in Fiddle but not when I run it on my side. I copy it exactly. http://jsfiddle.net/XWsvz/ has the data that I am receiving into the function and I put in your loop but instead of showing each property value it just iterates through each character as if it was plain text and has no other  meaning. I've been trying to figure this out for hours and it's frustrating... lol...

Answer (score 0):

> Now that I look at this, is it not the array of objects I'm expecting? How can I actually return the string so I can actually see what's really in it and maybe go from there?

If the object is being returned as a string, you can simply alert it. However, if your function is being passed an unknown object, you can always convert it back to a JSON string and alert it so that you can visualize the structure:

```
function displayItems(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    ...

}
```

As a sidenote, I changed the first letter in your function to a lowercase letter to match naming conventions for functions in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, normally I do use that camel casing but for some reason didn't on this one. Also, stringify just displayed "[object, Object]" so, basically just wrapped some quotes around it.

Comment: Ok, where is the alleged JSON coming from? A server? If so, try looking at the response in your Firebug or Chrome Debugger NET tab to see if you're really getting back JSON. Also, check that your server is returning the object using the mime-type "application-x/json" or "application/json".

Comment: Updated the question with more info for you to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're close:

```
function DisplayItems(data) {
    console.log('data is: ', JSON.stringify(data));
    $.each(data, function (key, arrayElement, index) {
        console.log('arrayElement ' + index + ' is: ', JSON.stringify(arrayElement));
        $.each(arrayElement, function (key, value) {
            console.log('key: ' + key + ' val: ' + value);
        });
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ux9D8/

With your data this gives me the following output:

```
data is:  [{"Name":"blah","Description":"blah"},{"Name":"blah2","Description":"blah2"}]
arrayElement undefined is:  {"Name":"blah","Description":"blah"}
key: Name val: blah
key: Description val: blah
arrayElement undefined is:  {"Name":"blah2","Description":"blah2"}
key: Name val: blah2
key: Description val: blah2
```

Comment: Console displays 

data is:  "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" and then writes out array element undefined is: "[" key: 0 val: [ and so on.

Comment: Works for me with your data, can you check my jsfiddle and let me know what's different on your end?