# iterating through a each key of a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

**Data**

```
   {
   "_id": "3fad6024-3226-451b-9e81-1c544aaaebf7",
   "name": "ank retailer part 2",
   "aboutUs": "part 2 updated",
   "retailerLanguage": [
      {
         "languageID": "20b4772c-2470-4eaa-bc0c-61429700781cd",
         "language": {
            "name": "Koreandddd",
            "__typename": "language"
         }
      },
      {
         "languageID": "8f04da56-0f53-4694-b6dc-0eb5a3aa2990",
         "language": {
            "name": "Mandarin",
            "__typename": "language"
         }
      }
   ],
   "termsAndConditions": "agreed"
}
```

I have tried this:

```
const tifOptionsES6 = Object.keys(d).map(key => {
  return Edited "{key}" to {d[key]} 
})
```

but unable to iterate for array key

**Expected Output**

```
Edited "name" to ank retailer part 2 
Edited "aboutUs" to part 2 updated
Edited "retailerLanguage" to Koreandddd , Mandarin
Edited "termsAndConditions" to part 2 agreed
```

and also check for not null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iteration Of JSON Array Of Objects Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509524/iteration-of-json-array-of-objects-not-working)

Comment: @Kinglish i want to use JavaScript only

Comment: @AgamS - Sorry my bad. Try this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020898/how-to-iterate-json-object-properly

Comment: @RahulKumar i ve a nested object inside an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nested object arrays, you will need to create a lookup map with function for accessing the nested data.

```js
const data = {
  "_id": "3fad6024-3226-451b-9e81-1c544aaaebf7",
  "name": "ank retailer part 2",
  "aboutUs": "part 2 updated",
  "retailerLanguage": [{
    "languageID": "20b4772c-2470-4eaa-bc0c-61429700781cd",
    "language": {
      "name": "Koreandddd",
      "__typename": "language"
    }
  }, {
    "languageID": "8f04da56-0f53-4694-b6dc-0eb5a3aa2990",
    "language": {
      "name": "Mandarin",
      "__typename": "language"
    }
  }],
  "termsAndConditions": "agreed"
}

const keyValueMap = {
  retailerLanguage: ({ language: { name } }) => name
};

const tifOptionsES6 = data =>
  Object.entries(data)
    .filter(([key]) => !key.startsWith('_'))
    .map(([key, value]) =>
      `Edited "${key}" to ${Array.isArray(value)
        ? value.map(e => keyValueMap[key]?.(e) ?? e).join(', ')
        : keyValueMap[key]?.(value) ?? value
      }`).join('\n');

console.log(tifOptionsES6(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you, and what if there are two arrays inside data Objects.    like we have this also:-  "retailerAgent": [{
    "agentID": "3t0772c-2470-4eaa-bc0c-61429700781cd",
    "agentName": {
      "name": "Mark",
      "__typename": "agent"
    }
  }, {
    "agentID": "d674da56-0f53-4694-b6dc-0eb5a3aa2990",
    "agentName": {
      "name": "Sunny",
      "__typename": "agent"
    }
  }],

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
const tifOptionsES6 = Object.keys(d).map(key => {
    const current = d[key]; // gets current element
    if (key.startsWith('_')) return ''; // exits if starts with _
    if (key == 'retailerLanguage') { // check for a key
        let names = []; // creates a new list
        for (elem of current) { // loop through elements of sub-array
            names.push(elem.language.name) // adds name to list
        }
        const formattedNames = names.reduce((a, c) => a + ', ' + c); // format names to be readable
        return `Edited "${key}" to ${formattedNames}` // return
    } else {
        return `Edited "${key}" to ${current}` // return
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to [Mr. Polywhirl's rock star solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67642200/15979256) here a very simple approach you would not use in the long run, but that illustrates the mechanics you need:

First: your

```
const tifOptionsES6 = Object.keys(d).map(key => {
  return Edited "{key}" to {d[key]}
})
```

is syntactically wrong, it should be something like

```
const tifOptionsES6 = Object.keys(d).map(key => {
  return 'Edited "' + key + '" to "' +  d[key]  ;
})
```

(You obviously tried around in a React playground?)

Note that Mr. Polywhirl uses [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) that have a dangerous similarity to [JSX's "{}" for placing JS code](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx) - we stay simple with string concatenation.

If your data is fixed as in your example, a very transparent way could go like this

```
const tifOptionsES6 = Object.keys(d).map(key => {
  if( key === 'retailerLanguage' ) {
    d[key].forEach( entry =>
      'Edited "' + key + '" to "' +  entry['language']['name'] 
    )
  } else {
    return 'Edited "' + key + '" to "' +  d[key] ;
  }
})
```

If you then make your way through the rich world of methods of JavaScript prototypes (eg. .filter(), .startswith()) up to [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (and are not in a business where you still have to suppport IE 9), you are ready to build upon Mr. Polywhirl's impressing solution.

Comment: thank you for your answer and what if is another array of objects inside data object like:-   "retailerAgent": [{
    "agentID": "3t0772c-2470-4eaa-bc0c-61429700781cd",
    "agentName": {
      "name": "Mark",
      "__typename": "agent"
    }
  }, {
    "agentID": "d674da56-0f53-4694-b6dc-0eb5a3aa2990",
    "agentName": {
      "name": "Sunny",
      "__typename": "agent"
    }
  }],